# Calculated column in SP 2010 returns error for one item in IF clause

Tags: if-statement, sharepoint-2010, calculated-columns

I have a calculated column that I want to use to show the timeliness of a process. In the library I have a field for deadlines, and a field for when a task was completed (Afronding, in Dutch). The column checks whether the completion date (delivered as an update after a workflow)is before, on time or after the deadline.

The column works and returns correct values for every case EXCEPT when the completion date is the same as the deadline. Then, in every case (and in multiple libraries) it returns a zero (0). It can't use the 0 in my status lists.

Any ideas as to why I'm getting a zero when the two look-up fields are identical? Both field are set to show a date, but no time.

Below is an example. "ALS" is Dutch for "IF". I've tried using IF as well, and get no syntax error, but the same result.

=ALS([Afronding schrijven]="";"Leeg";ALS([Afronding schrijven]<[Deadline schrijven];"Vroeg";ALS([Afronding schrijven]=[Deadline schrijven];"Op tijd";ALS([Afronding schrijven]=[Deadline schrijven]+1;"één dag laat";ALS([Afronding schrijven]=[Deadline schrijven]+2;"twee dagen laat";ALS([Afronding schrijven]>[Deadline schrijven]+2;"drie of meer dagen laat";))))))

Comment: You have what looks like an unreachable branch at the very end-- if `[Afronding schrijven]>[Deadline schrijven]+2` evaluates to false, the formula does not define a return value. I'm curious, if you change your formula to this: `=ALS([Afronding schrijven]="";"Leeg";ALS([Afronding schrijven]<[Deadline schrijven];"Vroeg";ALS([Afronding schrijven]=[Deadline schrijven];"Op tijd";ALS([Afronding schrijven]=[Deadline schrijven]+1;"één dag laat";ALS([Afronding schrijven]=[Deadline schrijven]+2;"twee dagen laat";"drie of meer dagen laat"))))))` will it show "drie of meer dagen laat" instead of zero?

Comment: Yep, that did it. I needed to remove one closing parentheses from the end of the formula, but then it worked perfect. Thanks for the quick response!